# CakePHP3 : flash not working with Japanese characters

Tags: cakephp, cjk, flash-component

In my controller

```
 $this->Flash->success('This is working');//OK

 $this->Flash->success('日本語');//not working
```

success.ctp

```
<?php
if (!isset($params['escape']) || $params['escape'] !== false) {
    $message = h($message);
}
?>
<div class="message success alert alert-success alert-dismissible" onclick="this.classList.add('hidden')"><?= $message ?></div>
```

I working on cakePHP version 3.5
How to show flash with Japanese characters .
Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean 'not working'? what is your cake version?

Comment: @arilia: this message do not display. 
But I have find my mistake. 
In my sessions table, [Collation] was encoding such as latin, UTF-8